# run cgi file from xampp localhost on mac osx

Tags: python, apache, xampp, cgi

i am a complete noob to python scripts. I am following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe) tutorial to do some iOS stuff. This includes `python cgi script` integration as well.

I have successfully made the cgi file but am not able to run it.

File path is: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/payment-test.cgi`

In browser I run the file as: `http://localhost/cgi-bin/payment-test.cgi`

I get the following error:

```
 Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
Premature end of script headers: payment-test.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Sat Oct 11 12:24:29 2014
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

I have modified `httpd.conf` by following [this](http://mycsmanual.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/how-to-make-xampp-handle-cgi-applications-written-in-python/) link.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: It's preferred that code samples are posted here on SO, not linked to external sites. But that script looks pretty basic. Can you run _any_ cgi? Eg `#! /usr/bin/env python` `print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>'` ? Don't forget to set execute permissions on the file.

Comment: "Premature end of script headers" is indicative of the cgi configuration not being correct, or the script being run not being a cgi script.